# Removing trailing decimal in email

Tags: email, email-template

I am displaying attributes that are of type Number (18,0) in an email using a Visual Force template. I am referenced the attributes in the template in the normal way. However, they are displayed as:

```
18.0
16.0
```

Whereas I want them displayed as

```
18
16
```

Any ideas what I have to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like in [that example from salesforce](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm):

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, integer}">
    <apex:param value="{!someDouble}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the [expression functions reference](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?language=en&id=customize_functions.htm), you should find something that fits.

`{!ROUND(myObject__c.myField__c,0)}` maybe?

Or even `{!SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(myObject__c.myField__c), '.0', '')}`

But if it's VF page template - mast0r's answer is the preferred way as it gives you more control (my formulas can still be used if you have plaintext email for example).